# Novation launchkey 61 mk2 + Linux?

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard

Novation launchkey 61 mk2 + Linux ?? Maybe somebody has experience with its connecting ? I searched a lot in google, tried, but it's nothing worked. Keyboard isn't detected...

**Update:** add input device info

amidi -l

[image]

lsusb

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem really on topic, but, anyway, I'll go in StackOverflow mode. What do you mean by "I can't connect"? What are you trying to connect it to? What makes you think that you cannot "connect" it to what? The LaunchKey should be a standard USB MIDI compliant, so you should be able to see it at least with ALSA programs *and* Jack programs as long as the correct Jack MIDI backend is selected. Please provide more context, as right now trying to answer to your question is really like shooting in the dark.

Comment: To clarify: "USB MIDI compliant" means that it doesn't need any "driver" (aka: kernel module or some level of system abstraction) in order to be correctly recognized and used by the system and its libraries. Most of MIDI interfaces (keyboards, synths, controllers) that have been released in the last 10-15 years are usually such devices, at least to provide their basic interaction, unless they have very peculiar behavior or have very advanced features like "analog" parameters or very precise/multidimentional controllers (eg. the ROLI Seaboard). The LaunchKey should be *very* compliant.

Comment: To follow up on the previous comments: are you using Jack?

Comment: Does the device show up in the output of `lsusb`, `amidi -l`, and `arecordmidi -l`?

Comment: Idon't clearly know all the way of connecting midi with linux and steps about setting it up. I know that on the Windows I have to install drivers, open synthesizer, choose input output in settings etc and all works!  Here I thought I should connect my Keyboard by usb and open synthezer, choose input in settings and all ok. But it's not enough how I understood...

Comment: There is no keyboard in the Qsynth input device/audio device all the same(I tried change drivers from drop-down list and other fields...)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it probably belongs on a more computer orientated site, maybe SuperUser or possibly Ubuntu.

Comment: You have to connect the keyboard to Qsynth in routing window of Jack normally. Or using Patchage, possibly needing to convert the midi flow from alsa-midi to jack-midi with something like a2jmidi

Comment: @PiedPiper, no, I think it's right place. Because if someone tuned all this, then only the musicians, why would a simple computer engineer connect a midi that he does not have? So I absolutely disagree with you.

Comment: To be clear about the scope of this question: have you ever succeeded in getting a MIDI keyboard to work with a synth on GNU/Linux? In other terms, do you have this problem only with the novation, or is the question: "how to connect a midi keyboard to a synth in GNU/Linux?"

Comment: @Tom, It's my first midi keyboard. I don't ever connect any midi keyboard to linux. I tried ask for my friends, who plays on midi, but nobody knows about linux. But I need it.

Comment: I do. Read a bit on Jack and alsa, there are plenty of Tuto online. As it is, this is quite out of scope here...

Comment: I am new to music, and theres alot I do not know, but Ive used this midi controller with custom scripts I wrote using `aseqdump` to read raw IO.
In `helm` it autodetects, and works fine. Im on ubuntu 20 /22
novation seems to have an online interface... but I haven't gotten it to work yet. 
 this question might be better if migrated to Unux&Linux stack exchange, or askUbuntu